# Why is my snakemake rule with wildcards turned into a localrule?

Tags: snakemake

So, I made this simple Snakefile and I am wondering why my rule is interpreted as a `localrule`. Usually it's not a problem, but for my runs that need be submitted to SLURM it is. The only way I got it to work was writing the rule explicitly without wildcards. Then it was not interpreted as localrule. But then I obviously loose all the benefits of wildcards for my rules... I guess there is something I am missing here!

```
rule test:
  output: "bla4_out.txt",

rule test_wild:
  input: "bla{num}.txt",
  output: "bla{num}_out.txt",
  shell:
    """
touch {output}"
    """
```

This:
`snakemake -n -R test`
leads to

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Job stats:
job      count    min threads    max threads
-----  -------  -------------  -------------
test         1              1              1
total        1              1              1


[Mon May  9 13:02:41 2022]
localrule test:
    output: bla4_out.txt
    jobid: 0
    resources: tmpdir=/tmp

Job stats:
job      count    min threads    max threads
-----  -------  -------------  -------------
test         1              1              1
total        1              1              1

This was a dry-run (flag -n). The order of jobs does not reflect the order of execution.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a rule doesn't have a directive that does something, like `shell` or `run`, then that rule is stamped as local. I guess it makes sense though... Try adding a dummy `shell` directive to your rule `test` and see what happens.

Comment: Wow! that solved it! Thank you! Good to know... I guess I might write a bug report then??

Comment: I don't think it warrants a bug report, but it's up to you if you see it as a bug... I cannot see any reason for a rule to have no action anyway. Only the first rule, which pulls everything, needs no action.

Comment: I could also see a dummy rule that outputs a `touch` file being suitable for automatic local running.  I didn't know this and have been adding 'all' to my local rules!

Comment: It's definitely not a bug, but optimization (nothing to execute = no need for cluster submission, hence rule is local).

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev you and Troy are right, I edited my answer to remove the hint of a bug